# How to add filters for specific columns using apache poi?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have created a excel file format using apache poi, i was adding filters using the below code

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A3:C3"));
```

This code will create filter from A to C 3rd row also i added below code

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E3:H3"));
```

This code will create filters from E to H on 3rd row, but the first code is not working if the second code is executed. my concern is i don't want D column to enable filter. I have tried like below code but doesn't work only last executed code column filter is enabled.

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("E3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("F3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("G3"));
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("H3"));
```

but last executed code H column only filter is enabling. Can anyone help me except D column to enable for remaining columns A, B, C, E, F, G, H.

Using apache poi and used default methods for XSSFSheet and tried to add filters for specific columns but not working.

Comment: Have you tried to achieve this using Excel's GUI? It is not possible. There is only one **one** auto-filter setting possible per sheet.

Comment: atleast is there any hide options for column to hide auto filter?

Comment: [Sheet.setColumnHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnHidden-int-boolean-)